# Borwser: didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, ruby-on-rails-4, browser, browser-cache

I am on rails 4 framework and using nginx werbserver and passenger as a application server. Sometimes while trying to load web page i am getting below error and my web page is not loading.

```
didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I checked my server log file and found that request is not hitting to the server at all. after clearing the browser cache it is working fine.

what can be the reason for this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: any success using different browser?

Comment: I am getting this issue in all browsers.

Comment: can you run `htop` on your server and see is nginx running?

Comment: need to install htop.. but my nginx is running because other computers in my office getting the proper response back. This issue occurs sometimes and not coming whenever i cleared my browser cache.